# String splitting in Python

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

Is there a way to split a string in Python using multiple delimiters instead of one? `split` seems to take in only one parameter as delimiter.

Also, I cannot import the `re` module. (This is the main stumbling block really.)

Any suggestions on how I should do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with importing re?  What error does it give you?

Comment: I'm working on a Python UDF for Pig with a jython jar which is giving me issues. Working off an existing system here. Not inclined to fight legacy. I only need to use 3 delimiters. The number of delimiters is not a parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to split on multiple sequences you could simply replace all of the sequences you need to split on with just one sequence and then split on that one sequence.

So

```
s = s.replace("z", "s")
s.split("s")
```

Will split on s and z.

Answer (score 1):

Generic approach for a list of splitters, please, someone can write this with less code?

**Initializing vars:**

```
>>> splits = ['.', '-', ':', ',']
>>> s='hola, que: tal. be'
```

**Splitting:**

```
>>> r = [ s ]
>>> for p in splits:
...    r =  reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda z: z.split(p), r ))
```

**Results:**

```
>>> r
['hola', ' que', ' tal', ' be']
```